# How to fix Pandas KeyError : len(df) = 5000, but df.loc[809] results in keyerror

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I am using index to access a row in pandas,

```
   index = random.randint(0,len(df))
   song = [df.loc[index]['Artist'], df.loc[index]['Song']]    
   print(song)
```

the index is always within the length of the df, and it is working well on most pulls, but from time to time i am getting this error and i am struggling to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df.loc` uses index (values from `df.index`) not the position of the row. Did you mean to use `.iloc` instead:

```
index = random.randint(0,len(df))
song = [df.iloc[index]['Artist'], df.iloc[index]['Song']]    
print(song)
```